# Video not looping in windows adobe reader

Tags: beamer, media9, movie15, multimedia

I embedded a video in beamer presentation file using the media9 package. The video loops as it is supposed to in my desktop which runs a mac, but it does not loop in windows adobe reader. It plays however on click, but does not loop.
Here is the code:

```
\includemedia[
label=vidA,
addresource=new.mp4,
activate=pageopen,
width=6.5cm, height = 7.5cm,
flashvars={
%autoPlay = true
source=new.mp4
&loop=true&stretching=uniform&
autostart=true&repeat=always&smoothing=true
}
]{}{VPlayer.swf}
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I've tried Both Acrobat Reader DC and Adobe Reader 11.0.10.